# How hard is it to read flash memory off a chip?

Tags: physical, flash-memory

What are the parameters in play, and what is a rough estimate of the hardness of the task of reading the contents of flash memory off a microcontroller? Of course, it is assumed that there is no conventional way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

It largely depends on the chip and the person that programmed it. Microcontrollers usually have a feature that allows you to pull the existing firmware binary off, but in many cases that can be disabled with a so-called "secure flag", which disables the download process until a new firmware is uploaded containing directives that turn the secure flag off. Of course, this wipes the existing firmware in the process. Check the datasheet for the microcontroller for specifics.

If it's a *microprocessor* (as opposed to a microcontroller) then there is usually no on-chip firmware, and the program code is stored externally on a memory device. Usually this will be an EEPROM or a mask ROM which you can interface with separately. I've done this with embedded systems that use SPI flash - just desolder it and hook it up to a Bus Pirate. If you can't desolder the device, it may also be possible to sniff the bus and gain information that way.

The universal way to get at the data is decapping. You get some strong acid (nitric acid is a common choice) that will eat away and the package compound, but not the silicon, and leave it in there for a day or two. You then take photographs with a digital microscope and use image processing to turn the patterns into data.

Comment: Can we get more details on the commands or steps one would take using a Bus Pirate?

Comment: @atdre It entirely depends on the flash chip. It could have an SPI or I2C interface, or something totally different. Then on top of that there'll be commands and steps that are unique to that device. It's impossible to give a catch-all. You have to read the datasheet and the BusPirate manual.

Comment: That's a fair answer. What would you do if you had a bigger budget and also pretend that Bus Pirate didn't exist. What would you use instead? Isn't the Bus Pirate just a glorified serial-friendly vesion of the Arduino but made by TI?

Comment: The BusPirate is a device which is designed to be a programmable interface with various bus types, with minimal implementation overhead. It is designed for interfacing with individual components without supporting circuitry. It and the Arduino do two completely different things. Also, the BusPirate is made by Dangerous Prototypes, not TI. If I had a big budget I'd probably still use a BusPirate, simply because it's so easy to use. I would probably buy a proper logic analyser to support it, though.

Comment: Excellent answer! What types of probes/cables do you use with the BusPirate? Syringes? Tweezer-style clips? Pin leads or probe cables? Connectorized or separated? Besides test targets, I'd be curious to hear about your toolkit for use with the BusPirate, which test accessories you use, and how you assemble them. Hate to go too off topic, but my curiosity is peaked!

Comment: The BP comes with a set of female pins that connect to headers, but you can also buy alternative headers that has hook probes and tweezer clips. I use both. You can also clip various things into the standard headers anyway. It's mainly designed for easy integration into through-hole / breadboard stuff, as it primarily targets the hobbyist market. When I'm dealing with SMD stuff I usually use the tweezer clips (pincer style ones) to hook onto the leads.

Comment: Interesting question can you visibly see the state of a rom?

Comment: @marshalcraft For a mask ROM, yes, because the data is directly part of the silicon. Think of it as a grid where you've got horizontal lines, each representing one address value (e.g. 0x00, 0x01, ... 0xFF for 256 horizontal lines on a 256-word ROM), and vertical lines, each representing a data bit (e.g. 8 lines for a ROM with 8-bit word size). At the intersection of each line there is optionally a diode tying the vertical line to the horizontal, and the presence of that diode represents a 1 whereas the absence represents a 0. You can see these diodes under a microscope.

Comment: @marshalcraft The way it works is that the vertical lines each get pulled up to +Vcc via a resistor, and at the bottom of each vertical line there is an inverter that is connected to an output data line. The horizontal address lines are also all held at +Vcc. By default this pulls the inputs of all of the inverters up, thus outputting a 0 on all of the data output pins. When an address is put on the address pins of the ROM, the address decoder pulls the corresponding horizontal line to ground. Where diodes are present, this pulls the vertical line down to 0V, thus making the inverter output 1.

Comment: @marshalcraft You can see an example of a mask ROM circuit [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/digital-circuits-5-memories/read-only-memory). In some cases a diode is always included at every junction, but with a fuse in series. Each fuse can be blown or left intact in order to set the data bit as 0 or 1 respectively. Other designs use a transistor at each junction with a fuse on the base, but the principle is the same. One-time programmable ROM (PROM) devices work the same way, but the fuses are blown via an overcurrent when you program them, rather than during the silicon manufacturing phase.